# AVD won't launch (SDK Tools 22.6.2)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, adt, android-virtual-device

I downloaded the ADT bundle (22.6.2). When opening the Android SDK Manager I saw the version of SDK Tools was 22.3, upgrade available for SDK Tools 22.6.2. I tried running an emulator first and that worked perfectly. After that I installed SDK Tools 22.6.2, along with other API's. When I tried opening an emulator again, it did not work.

I can create, edit and delete AVD's. But they won't start. After I hit `launch`, I get the `Starting Android Device`screen, en the bar fills, but nothing happens. I tried playing around with different targets, different devices, different RAM but to no avail.

I tried killing the adb server and restarting it. Nothing changes. No device shows up as well when I try `adb devices`, even though I made them in the AVD Manager.

I feel like the problem has to do with the SDK Tools having rev. 22.6.2. Because when I use a fresh install (SDK Tools being 22.3), everything works.

Anyone knows a solution or is going back to SDK Tools 22.3 the only one?

EDIT: This is on OS X 10.6.8, not sure if this was worth mentioning.

EDIT 2: My apologies for not replying for a long time. Anyways, the problem is still not fixed.
When I checked for updates, none were available. When I tried installing new software it told me everything was installed already. I used https as well as http. I unchecked “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”.
I still have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 33):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) is the steps from android.com. I had the save problem. This works for me.

1.Download the [ADT-22.6.2 Plugin zip file](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.2.zip) (do not unpack it).
2.Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3.Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4.In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5.Select the downloaded ADT-22.6.2.zip file and click OK.
6.Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7.In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
8.In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9.Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
10.When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Comment: In de ADT bundle I have, Eclipse has already the 22.6.2 plugin. So this does not change anything.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me although I still see 22.0.xxx on the Splash Screen when opening ADT on a Mac

Answer (score 13):

I have had the same problem today. I tried to restart Eclipse, check for updates and no updates were available.

The solution for me was to open *Eclipse/Help/Install new software*, add this URL in the "Work with" section:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

and install the Developer tools.

Comment: I am getting a similar error to the OP. WHen I try this fix, i get an error:  An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package,22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508...

Answer (score 5):

If you look at:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

it tells you to use https on the android update site, changing the "Android Developer Tools Update Site" to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From this thread, http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jvmmonitor/issues/detail?id=82

"Quick answer: Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”"

The check box is inside Help->Install New Software->Install

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to re-install the ADT 22.6.2 plug-in. 
To re-install, firstly browse to your eclipse folder (the place you extracted eclipse).
In the root of the eclipse folder, you have a folder named "plugins". Delete all the contents of the folder. Now, direct your browser to go here and download the ADT 22.6.2 zip archive : [ADT 22.6.2 zip archive](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.2.zip)

Do not unpack the archive. Launch eclipse. Go to Help -> Install new software -> Click on 'Add' -> Give it a name like "ADT Plugin' -> Click on archive and browse to lacation where you just downloaded the ADT zip archive and select it -> Hit OK - > Accept the license agreements and proceed with the installation.

Regards!

Comment: In de ADT bundle I have, Eclipse has already the 22.6.2 plugin. So this does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, and fixed it as follows:

- I removed all ADT and Android plugins. On OSX this is done via `Eclipe (menu) > About Eclipse`. On Windows via `Help > About Eclipse` and then the button `Installation details`.
- Then I reinstalled the ADT plugin via `Help > Install new software`
- Check for updates.
- Uncheck `Hide items that are already installed`, because then the update that you need might be hidden.
- Check only the 22.6.2 update and run it.
- Restart Eclipse and see if the problem is fixed.
- Then install all updates as needed.

That fixed it for me.