# Eclipse ADT Version requires Update 22.6.2 or above but i already Updated it

Tags: android, eclipse, updates, updating

I'm having problem with the ADT update my current version is 22.0.4 it did not renew my current version. i already downloaded the the new Version from the SDK manager Update 22.6.2. But when i open my Eclipse my current version is still the 22.0.4. How can i resolve this problem. I tried to check for updates and it pop-ups No Updates Found and an error of 'No Repository Found at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x.

How can i Fix it? What are the this i could to in setting up my ADT?

I also tried Install new Software from this link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but i couldn't install in because i already installed the new updates..

> Here is the error when i open my Eclipse

[image]

[image: Here is my ADT Installation Details]

> My SDK Manager

[image]

Comment: is it telling you that you need an update? This might be similar to a problem I once had

Comment: yes it tells me i need an update but i already updated the new updetes from the SDK manager.. but when i open my eclipse my version is still 22.0.4 not 22.6.2 i just saw it from the ADT luncher

Comment: Try closing out Eclipse and open it back up by running it as administrator. (I assume that you are on Windows)

Comment: same thing happened. :(

Comment: i don't know why my ADT could cont find update.. when i check it from the ADT installation information it's still 22.0.4

Comment: You are making the distinction between ADT updates and SDK updates, correct? Each is updated separately.

Comment: yes. but what's wrong with my ADT and SDK setup i already updated it from the SDK manager...

Comment: Well, I've exhausted my supply of ideas. I have had to do a fresh install before. It might be easier than seeking a solution sadly.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22683012/783051

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same exact problem. It seems like you have just updated the SDK version to 22.6.2 or above using the Android SDK Manager but you haven't updated the ADT plugin.

Go to **Help > Install New Software...**

Then enter the following in the **Work with:** field

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Wait for the updates to complete.